# Trim url to last path until host is reached

Tags: .net, vb.net

I wrote a small amount of code to trim a url to last path, until host is reached, but it doesn't work as it should:

```
Dim line As String
line = "http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/"
line = Replace(line, "http://", "")

Dim count As Integer
count = line.Split("/").Length - 1

For x = count To 1 Step -1
    count = line.Split("/").Length - 1
    Dim lastpath As String = line.Split("/")(x).Split("/")(0)
    Dim newline As String = Replace(line, "/" & lastpath, "")
    MsgBox(newline)
```

In my situtation I would like to see 5 box message with url without last path:

```
www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4
www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3
www.domain.com/folder1/folder2
www.domain.com/folder1
www.domain.com
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: What output *do* you get? Don't expect everyone to run your code.

Comment: I am getting "www.domain.comfolder1folder2folder3folder4" "www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/" "www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder4/" "www.domain.com/folder1/folder3/folder4" "www.domain.com/folder2/folder3/folder4"

Comment: You can probably simplify this code by repeatedly doing something like `line = line.Substring(0, line.LastIndexOf('/'))` (but check whether LastIndexOf returns -1, indicating no more slashes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class?

```
Dim uri As New Uri("http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/")
```

Then you could get all information you need using [`Uri.Host`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx) and [`Uri.Segments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx)